# libfreetype-6.dll lost when using GRASS command line

Tags: grass-gis, windows-8, command-line, grass.script

Update#1：

Following the instruction of Sorin Călinică, I have installed `libfreetype-6.dll` using the `OSGeo4W Network Installer`, and the command `d.rast` can launch successfully.

---

I am using GRASS 6.4.3 (installed with osGeo4w), and I have this question：

Whenever I want to use the `d.rast` command, I got the error message about **system error of d.rast.exe** that I lost **libfreetype-6.dll**：
[image]

How can I solve this problem? I am using GRASS 6.4.3 under windows 8.1 64-bits, please give me any suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you don't have `libfreetype-6.dll` installed on your system.

Just launch the `OSGeo4W Network Installer (64 bit)` > `Advenced Install`, type *freetype* in the search box and perform the freetype packages installing.

[image]

Then, `libfreetype-6.dll` must be installed on your computer:

[image]

Comment: Dear Heinz, i suggest you to ask a new question for your new problem, first because it is against this site rules to address multiple issues in a single question and second, you'll have more chances to receive a quick and a proper answer!

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, I'll edit this post and ask my questions in another post.